# What is the exploded path of a jar downloaded by jnlp?

Tags: java, jar, io, sandbox, jnlp

I have a web app. packaged as a jar file and served by Java Web Start using jnlp. When the user runs my program, it generates an excel file, which is to be shown by a web page within the same app.

The question is: where should my java class write the excel file so that the web page is able to locate/serve it? Obviously, web page can read from within the web app only (sandbox). But the only handle that I can get to the jnlp downloaded app is the jar file (which is not modifiable at runtime) and not EXPLODED jar file contents. If I am able to locate and write to the exploded jar file contents, I can write my excel file there to be picked up by the web page.

Any help? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..where should my java class write the excel file so that the web page is able to locate/serve it?

Write it to a sub-directory of `user.home`. Either that or to the `temp.dir` (spelling?).

Either of those apps. should be writable be a Java app. without special permissions (e.g. running as root).

Comment: Thanks, but in that case, how will my html page be able to serve the written file? For eg. the javascript window.location = '<<path>>', will not be able to find this path (since it can recognize only files inside the same webapp). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: *"how will my html page be able to serve the written file?"*  Wait ..what?  The web-app. or the desktop app.?  The web app. will not have access to **any** paths on the client machine, within or outside the installation path of the desktop app.